# Merge/flatten multidimensional array and remove duplicates Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
var workouts = [
  [0, Object, 0, 0, 0],
  [Object, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, Object, 0]
];
```

I'd like to flatten/merge the array and remove the duplicates. The result should look something like this:

```
[Object, Object, 0, Object, 0]
```

Is it possible to perform?

Comment: How are you defining removing duplicates? Why is 0 in your result twice, is that not a duplicate? What have you tried?

Comment: only 2 zeroes are there in your expected Output.. Is that right? It supposed to have 3 zeroes isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it should be 2 zeros in the expected output. My plan is to loop the expected output and then render different elements depending on the 0 / the object.

Comment: Are you mapping the indices of inner arrays and mark the ones with the object if an inner array has an onbect at that index or 0 if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to keep the first encountered object in a given column if it exists.

You can do that with `.map()` and `.reduce()`:

```js
var workouts = [
  [0, {id:1}, 0, 0, 0],
  [{id:2}, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, {id:3}, 0]
];

var res = workouts.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return b.map(function(e, i) { return a[i] instanceof Object ? a[i] : e; });
}, []);


console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

Late for the party, but I still want to make use of:

- [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) for reducing the dimension to 1,
- [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for removing dupes
- [`Spread Syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for getting array out of that set.
- `JSON.stringify` and parse back for handling dupes of Objects.

Here's the code and a very inspirational posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/4636715) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601543/4636715):

```js
const myArray = [
  [0, {id:1}, 0, 0, 0],
  [{id:2}, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, {id:2}, 0]
]

const myFlatArray = myArray.flat()
const result = [...new Set(myFlatArray.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

**Note:** ES6 must be supported for this solution

Answer (score 0):

```
var workouts = [
  [0, {id:1}, 0, 0, 0],
  [{id:2}, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, {id:3}, 0]
];

function flattenArray (array){
  var newArray = [];
  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    var subArray = array[i];
    for (ii=0; ii<subArray.length; ii++){
      if (newArray.indexOf(subArray[ii]) == -1){
      newArray.push(subArray[ii]);
      }
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
console.log(flattenArray(workouts));
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxLrqL

Answer (score 0):

I  would do like this;

```js
var workouts = [[0, {a:1}, 0, 0, 0],
                [{b:2}, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, {c:3}, 0]
               ],
      result = workouts.reduce((p,c) => p = c.map((e,i) => e || p[i] || 0 ),[])
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't understand anything :(  all the inline code and non explanatory variables makes its super hard to read